# How to combine clauses LIKE and BETWEEN in same SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to execute an SQL query but i get nothing. I'd like to get the entrance back with two clauses, **LIKE** and **BETWEEN**.

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE address LIKE '%a%' AND price BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Need single quotes around `%a%` => `'%a%'`.

Comment: Exact, i forgot to note it but it wasn't that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE 
  address LIKE '%a%' 
  AND (price BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000)
```

second option

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE 
  address LIKE '%a%' 
  AND price >= 100000 
  AND price <= 200000
```

Comment: I don't understand cause I tried these and it didn't work and now it work ! Thanks !

Comment: @br-dev: this does not work better than your original query (parentheses are superfluous here). Your problem is that you are missing single quotes around literal string `'%a%'`, as commented by Paul T. on your question. This looks like a typo to me.